# Processing, simple "raytracing" engine "target VM failed to initialize"

Tags: graphics, 2d, processing

I've been trying to fix this thing for a while now but it doesn't seem to work; "Could not run the sketch (Target VM failed to initialize)."

I'll post the full code down below.

In the draw(), there are three for loops.

```
for(int i = 0; i<objectAmount; i++) {
  circles[i].drawObj();
}
```

The first one creates the circles, while the second nested ones take care of collision and drawing the lines;

```
for(int i = 0; i<rayAmount; i++) {
  rays[i].update();
  for(int j = 0; j<objectAmount; j++) {
    rays[i].collide(circles[j]);
  }
  line(rays[i].xPos, rays[i].yPos, rays[i].xEnd, rays[i].yEnd);
}
```

the .collide takes point on the 'ray' and moves closer to the circle until it reaches some value, where it marks the line's end, which is then used by the line() function to draw it to the circle.

For some reason, when I implemented the .collide function, everything stopped working *unless* I set the amount of rays to one, in which case no rays would appear but the circle generation would follow along just fine.

```
int rayAmount = 45;
int angleCorrect = 360/rayAmount;
int objectAmount = 10;
Ray[] rays = new Ray[rayAmount];
Object[] circles = new Object[objectAmount];

void setup() {
  size(600, 400, P2D);
  
  for(int i = 0; i<rayAmount; i++) {
    rays[i] = new Ray(i*angleCorrect);
  }
  for(int i = 0; i<objectAmount; i++) {
    circles[i] = new Object(random(0, 600), random(0, 400), random(20, 100));
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  stroke(100);
  
  for(int i = 0; i<objectAmount; i++) {
    circles[i].drawObj();
  }
  for(int i = 0; i<rayAmount; i++) {
    rays[i].update();
    for(int j = 0; j<objectAmount; j++) {
      rays[i].collide(circles[j]);
    }
    line(rays[i].xPos, rays[i].yPos, rays[i].xEnd, rays[i].yEnd);
  }
}



class Ray {
  float xPos, yPos, Angle, xEnd, yEnd;
  
  Ray(float angle) {
    xPos = mouseX;
    yPos = mouseY;
    Angle = angle;
  }
  
  void update() {
    xPos = mouseX;
    yPos = mouseY;
    
    //xEnd = xPos + 100 * cos(radians(Angle));
    //yEnd = yPos + 100 * sin(radians(Angle));
  }
  
  void collide(Object other) {
    float newXEnd = this.xEnd;
    float newYEnd = this.yEnd;
    
    float distToObject = sqrt(pow(other.xPos-this.xPos, 2) + pow(other.yPos-this.yPos, 2));
    while(distToObject > 1) {
      newXEnd = newXEnd + distToObject * cos(radians(Angle));
      newYEnd = newYEnd + distToObject * sin(radians(Angle));
      
      distToObject = sqrt(pow(other.xPos-newXEnd, 2) + pow(other.yPos-newYEnd, 2));
    }
    this.xEnd = newXEnd;
    this.yEnd = newYEnd;
  }
}

class Object {
  float xPos, yPos, radius;
  
  Object(float x, float y, float r) {
    xPos = x;
    yPos = y;
    radius = r;
  }
  
  
  void drawObj() {
    stroke(100);
    circle(xPos, yPos, radius);    
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [debugging](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) your code? From what I can see, it looks like your `while` loop is not exiting. Is that what you expected?

Comment: Thank you! I haven’t solved the problem yet but i know now why it didn’t work; the For loop that checks the distance runs under the assumption some circle will be hit. It should terminate after about 10 iterations or so, so that it doesnt try to infinitely collide rays that are never going to collide. Thank you for leading me to it!

Comment: Also, on a Stackoverflow posting note: if your title mentions a JVM error, [please show that error in your post](/help/how-to-ask). Either it's related to your question, in which case you should show folks what you're looking at, or it's not, in which case it shouldn't be in your title either.